# how to ng-repeat values for result from filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

What is the best implementation for ng-repeat some items from array with depending for property (like: hidden: true).

```
var items = [
    {
       label: 'Fist item',
    },
    {
       label: 'Second item',
       hidden: true
    },
    {
       label: 'Third item',
    },
]
```

For result i want to see Fist & Third items that don't have hidden property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `filter` filter, which, [as it says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZhYH.jpg), will filter your array according to conditions you give it.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{hidden:false}">
  ...
</div>
```

Read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for more available filter values.

Another example would be to use a function in the scope, if you need better manipulation:

```
$scope.shouldFilter = function(item) {
  return item.hidden === false || !('hidden' in item);
}
```

---

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:shouldFilter">
  ...
</div>
```